# How to omit 0 and negative numbers, but user can enter for example 10 in angular materials

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

So I hava a Angular 8 application and I am using the Material angular library.
And I have a nummeric field. But I want to omit the user from entering negative numbers and the number 0. And I found a solution. But now a user can't even enter for example the number 10 - what is in this case a valid number.

I have this:

```
<ng-container>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input
                    matInput
                    type="number"
                    formControlName="maxAllowedToScan"
                    placeholder="Max allowed scanned"
                    i18n-placeholder
                    onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 49"
                    min="1"
                  />
                  <mat-error *ngIf="qrForm.get('maxAllowedToScan').invalid && qrForm.get('maxAllowedToScan').dirty">
                    {{ errors.maxAllowedToScan }}
                  </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
              </ng-container>
```

and this is what I have in the ts file:

```
 this.qrForm = this.fb.group({
      qrcode: [this.definition.qrcode, Validators.required],
      title: [this.definition.title, Validators.required],
      description: [this.definition.description, Validators.required],
      maxAllowedToScan: [
        this.definition.maxAllowedToScan // ,
        // this.requiredIfScanFrequencyTypeIsNotNone( scanFrequencyTypeControl, 'maxAllowedToScan' )
      ],
```

So my question is: how to improve this?

Thank you

But if I do this:

```
<ng-container>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input
                    matInput
                    type="number"
                    formControlName="maxAllowedToScan"
                    placeholder="Max allowed scanned"
                    i18n-placeholder
                    onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 49"
                  />
                  <mat-error *ngIf="qrForm.get('maxAllowedToScan').invalid && qrForm.get('maxAllowedToScan').dirty">
                    {{ errors.maxAllowedToScan }}
                  </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
              </ng-container>
```

then the user still can't enter the number 10 for example.

I tried like this:

```
 <ng-container>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input
                    matInput
                    type="number"
                    formControlName="maxAllowedToScan"
                    placeholder="Max allowed scanned"
                    i18n-placeholder
                    onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"
                    (change) = 'preventLeadingZero()'

                  />
```

Comment: the min = 1 should keep you from entering 0 or negative numbers. It isn't?

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple function to handle `(keypress)` event, which will check the input length and charCode entered and prevent entering leading zero, e.g.:

```
function preventLeadingZero(event) {
  const input = event.target.value;


  if (input.length === 0 && event.which === 48) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: Oke, thank you. But I am using Angular with FormBuilder. Is there not an option with Validators.min(0) for example? So that a user can't type the number 0 but can type for example the number 10

Comment: I mean and how can I use this funtion in the html?

Comment: Dima.  I edit the post. But How to use the function in the html?

Comment: Instead of ```onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 49"``` use ```(keypress)="preventLeadingZero($event)"```

Comment: Angular form validators can't restrict the input - they just **validating** it so that later on you can handle form errors. You can write your own validator functions, but you'll not be able to restrict input with those, take a look at official docs: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators